# How do I fill table cells with a background color?

Tags: tables, color, backgrounds

I'd like to fill the cells of a table with a background color. How can this be done?

Comment: For examples of how to do this, see [color only a cell of a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50349/5764) and/or [Color merged and regular cells in a table individually](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8891/5764).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The [xcolor](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/) provides support for coloring table rows in a variety of patterns.  The [colortbl](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/) can color rows, columns, cells and rules.

There is a nice [article](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf) by Lapo Filippo Mori in the PracTeX Journal that describes the usage of both packages.  Scroll down to section 4.

Comment: xcolor: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/ colortbl:http://www.tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/ (fixing links above)

Comment: @Sharpie Can the the xcolor package be used for completely coloring the table in one specific color in one go? I am trying to replicate the look of [this table](http://www.iom.edu/Reports/2011/Breast-Cancer-and-the-Environment-A-Life-Course-Approach/~/media/Files/Report%20Files/2011/Breast-Cancer-Environment/BC_tableforweb.jpg) for my report.  I read up on the colortbl package but it has a pretty [limited palette.](http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/)  Do you have any pointers on how to write minimal code for that table using xcolor? Most tips involving xcolor are about alternating colored rows.

Comment: This answer could be improved if instead of just linking, you could quote the relevant parts to make this a complete answer. Links tend to get stale over time.

Answer (score 5):

The package `nicematrix` provides tools to color background of cells in tabulars. With those tools, you will have a good output in the PDF viewers: the rules won't seem to disappear in those PDF viewers at some levels of zoom (eg Adobe Reader) and you won't see the thin white lines you have in some PDF viewers (eg Sumatra PDF).

First, there are tools with the syntax of `colortbl`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc>{\columncolor{blue!15}}c}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
\rowcolor{red!15}1 & 22 & 34 & 2346 \\
2346 & 2 & 246  & 2 \\
1 & 34 & 2346111 & 1 \\
\cellcolor{yellow!50}1222 & 0 & 34 & 463
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

If you prefer to have the formatting instructions outside the main array, it's also possible with instructions in the `\CodeBefore`.

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{nicematrix}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
 \CodeBefore
   \columncolor{blue!15}{3}
   \rowcolor{red!15}{1}
   \cellcolor{yellow!50}{4-1}
 \Body
 1 & 22 & 34 & 2346 \\
 2346 & 2 & 246  & 2 \\
 1 & 34 & 2346111 & 1 \\
 1222 & 0 & 34 & 463
 \end{NiceTabular}

 \end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

There is also a command `\Block` (initially designed to merge cells) which may be used to color zones in the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-*}{}1 & 22 & 34 & 2346 \\
2346 & 2 & 246  & 2 \\
\Block[fill=yellow!50,rounded-corners]{2-2}{0} & & 2346111 & 1 \\
& & 34 & 463
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the third code]

Eventually, if you have something special to draw, you may use Tikz and the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` under the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
\CodeBefore
  \tikz \fill [red!15] (1-|1) -- (5-|3) -- (1-|4) -- cycle ;
\Body
1 & 22 & 34 & 2346 \\
2346 & 2 & 246  & 2 \\
1 & 34 & 2346111 & 1 \\
1222 & 0 & 34 & 463
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]