# color only a cell of a table

Tags: tables, color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Color merged and regular cells in a table individually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/color-merged-and-regular-cells-in-a-table-individually)

I tried to color only a cell of my table but I don't know how do it. I found the method to color an entire row.How could I color only a cell of my table of a precise color?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example (MWE) showing how it can be obtained using [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)'s `table` option - this loads [`colortbl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|r}
  \hline
  Some & \cellcolor{blue!25}coloured & contents \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The line choices in the above MWE emphasizes the `tabular` structure. However, for aesthetically pleasing table construction, consider using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

Comment: `xcolor` gave me an options clash. `colortbl` also provides the `\cellcolor` command, so I used that instead

Comment: This works but . . . I use it to highlight one cell. However, I have horizontal lines btw the rows and the color overwrites the line. I use "\hline" to write the line. If I could write the line *after* I write the color then all would be well, but it seems that "hline" has to be the first thing in the row, doesn't work if it is the last thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Wayne: Do you see this problem at *all* zoom levels? This problem is typically browser/viewer-related. I know that Adobe (Acrobat) Reader suffers from missing lines, while SumatraPDF doesn't really. The rendering algorithms are different and it doesn't have anything to do with LaTeX.

Comment: Werner -- thanks for pointing that out. I have now checked, it is worst in the default PDF used by TextStudio for Mac. Best in Adobe Acrobat. Middling bad in Apple's Preview. I ended up changing the textcolor in the cell -- something that seems to work equally well in the three.

Comment: I'd like to use this feature with the numprint package, but the number expands without formatting when the color is introduced.. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @Charlie: So you're using something like `\colorcell{<colour>}\numprint{<number>}` and `\numprint` doesn't format the number? If so, provide some code that replicates this behaviour. Perhaps consider asking a new question.

Comment: Yes. Actually, I got it working. I embraced the \colorcell{<color>}, which worked without issue. That is, I used {\colorcell{<color>}}.

Answer (score 77):

Use the `colortbl` package and its macro  `\cellcolor{<color>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Set some local commands and colors
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}
\newcommand{\done}{\cellcolor{teal}done}  %{0.9}
\newcommand{\hcyan}[1]{{\color{teal} #1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\done & other\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```