# Producing LaTeX Table

Tags: tables

Im relatively new to LaTeX and trying to create the table below, but so far I'm unsuccessful. Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Can you please show us what you have tried until now?

Comment: Have a look at [color-only-a-cell-of-a-table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50349/color-only-a-cell-of-a-table). Btw, you'll usual get help faster, and help that addresses what you're trying to ask, if you include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as part of your question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Gonzalo Medina's approach is indeed a good solution. When you are relatively new to LaTeX and want to find out more about how to work with tables: have a look at [LaTeX/Tables - Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). It has some clear examples and descriptions on how to use the `\multirow{}` and `\multicolumn{}` commands to create table cells which span multiple rows or colums. It also provides information on colouring table cells.

Answer (score 1):

Two options: the first one produces the table as you posted it. In the second option I suppressed the vertical rules and the colors and used the features from the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package (using [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) the table could be further improved):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{gray!30}}l*{4}{|l}|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!30}\bfseries Interest rates} \\
\cline{2-5}
\bfseries Stock & &  \bfseries Decline & \bfseries Increase & \bfseries Unit \\
\bfseries Price & & & & \bfseries Frequency \\
\cline{2-5}
& \bfseries Decline & 200 & 950 & 1150 \\
\cline{2-5}
& \bfseries Increase & 800 & 50 & 850 \\
\cline{2-5}
& & 1000 & 1000 & 2000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup\par\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries Interest rates} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(r){5-5}
\bfseries Stock & &  \bfseries Decline & \bfseries Increase & \bfseries Unit \\
\bfseries Price & & & & \bfseries Frequency \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \bfseries Decline & 200 & 950 & 1150 \\
& \bfseries Increase & 800 & 50 & 850 \\
& & 1000 & 1000 & 2000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\noindent`s and the group for the first table won't be necessary if the tables are inside a `table` environment.

Comment: \begin{center}   
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c}  
  \hline
   Stock Price/Interest Rate & Decline & Increase & Unit     frequency\\ 
   \hline \hline
   Decline & 200 & 950 & 1150\\
   Increase & 800 & 50 & 850\\
    & 1000 & 1000 & 2000\\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \end{center}                                                 This is what I have done so far. It is just the labelling of the rows and columns I a quite unsure of. Thanks for the quick responses, you are all a life saver to me.