# How can I recreate this layout in LaTeX, preferably using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I was trying to make it on my own, but my skills aren't enough to solve it.

[image]

Comment: There's the `\cellcolor` command of `xcolor`, why wouldn't you use that and ask for a TikZ solution? TikZ is not an universal saviour! Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8891/11002

Comment: @tohecz isn't that "the `\cellcolor` command of `colortbl`..." ?

Comment: @Thruston Yes, it seems so.

Comment: @tohecz: for the particular case, also TikZ seems to be fine and on purpose as the structure can be treated as two separate matrices.

Answer (score 28):

TikZ has one advantage here. Once appropiate styles are defined, the syntax of the matrix can be as easy as:

```
\matrix[options...]
{
Learning unit 1  & & &X&X&X& & \\
Learning unit 2  & & &X&X&X& & \\
Learning unit 3  &X&X&X& &X&X& \\
Learning unit 4  & & &X&X&X&X& \\
Learning unit 5  & & &X&X&X& & \\
Learning unit 6  & & &X&X&X&X&X\\
Learning unit 7  &X&X&X&X&X&X&X\\
Learning unit 8  &X&X& & &X&X& \\
Learning unit 9  &X&X& & &X&X&X\\
Learning unit 10 &X&X& & &X&X& \\
Learning unit 11 &X& & & &X& & \\
Learning unit 12 & & & &X&X&X&X\\
Learning unit 13 & & & &X& &X&X\\
Learning unit 14 &X& & &X&X& & \\
Learning unit 15 &X& & &X&X& & \\
};
```

The trick is to use `column 2`, `column 3`, etc styles that set the background color and foreground color to the desired "block" color, so that those "X" are not visible.

This is the complete code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Define appropiate colors for each block
\colorlet{block1}{green!60!yellow!80!black}
\colorlet{block2}{blue!80!red!70!black}
\colorlet{block3}{orange}
\colorlet{block4}{blue!50!cyan}
\colorlet{block5}{orange!50!red}
\colorlet{block6}{yellow}
\colorlet{block7}{black!30}

% This style sets the background and foreground color to #1,
% and fixes the size of the "X" cells
\tikzset{
  block/.style={#1, nodes={fill=#1, minimum height=4.5mm, minimum width=4.5mm}}
}

% Now the matrix
\matrix (M) [
  inner sep=0pt,
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={inner sep=0pt},
  column 1/.style={nodes={ % Column 1 is different
              text width=4cm, minimum height=4mm, inner sep=2pt,
              font=\sffamily\scriptsize,
           }},
  column 2/.style={block=block1},
  column 3/.style={block=block2},
  column 4/.style={block=block3},
  column 5/.style={block=block4},
  column 6/.style={block=block5},
  column 7/.style={block=block6},
  column 8/.style={block=block7},
] 
{
Learning unit 1  & & &X&X&X& & \\
Learning unit 2  & & &X&X&X& & \\
Learning unit 3  &X&X&X& &X&X& \\
Learning unit 4  & & &X&X&X&X& \\
Learning unit 5  & & &X&X&X& & \\
Learning unit 6  & & &X&X&X&X&X\\
Learning unit 7  &X&X&X&X&X&X&X\\
Learning unit 8  &X&X& & &X&X& \\
Learning unit 9  &X&X& & &X&X&X\\
Learning unit 10 &X&X& & &X&X& \\
Learning unit 11 &X& & & &X& & \\
Learning unit 12 & & & &X&X&X&X\\
Learning unit 13 & & & &X& &X&X\\
Learning unit 14 &X& & &X&X& & \\
Learning unit 15 &X& & &X&X& & \\
};

% Now draw the row lines
\foreach \i in {1,...,14} 
  \draw[gray] (M-\i-1.south west) -- (M-\i-1.south-|M.east);
% And the frame around the matrix
\draw[thick] (M.south west) rectangle (M.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: Table]

## Update

The style for the column 1 can be moved to a new tikz style, which allows us to reuse it for the other "lengend" table.

This is the complete code for both tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\colorlet{block1}{green!60!yellow!80!black}
\colorlet{block2}{blue!80!red!70!black}
\colorlet{block3}{orange}
\colorlet{block4}{blue!50!cyan}
\colorlet{block5}{orange!50!red}
\colorlet{block6}{yellow}
\colorlet{block7}{black!30}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={#1, nodes={fill=#1, minimum height=4.5mm, minimum width=4.5mm}},
  headings/.style= {nodes={
              text width=4cm, minimum height=4mm, inner sep=2pt,
              font=\sffamily\scriptsize}
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (M) [          % Legend table
   inner sep = 0pt,
   matrix of nodes,
   nodes={inner sep=0pt},
   column 1/.style=headings,
   row 1 column 2/.style={block=block1},
   row 2 column 2/.style={block=block2},
   row 3 column 2/.style={block=block3},
   row 4 column 2/.style={block=block4},
   row 5 column 2/.style={block=block5},
   row 6 column 2/.style={block=block6},
   row 7 column 2/.style={block=block7},
] {
Block 1. Lorem ipsum  &X\\
Block 2. Lorem ipsum  &X\\
Block 3. Lorem ipsum  &X\\
Block 4. Lorem ipsum  &X\\
Block 5. Lorem ipsum  &X\\
Block 6. Lorem ipsum  &X\\
Block 7. Lorem ipsum  &X\\
};

\foreach \i in {1,...,6} 
  \draw[gray] (M-\i-1.south west) -- (M-\i-1.south-|M.east);
\draw[thick] (M.south west) rectangle (M.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\hskip 1cm
%
\begin{tikzpicture}  % Second table
\matrix (M) [
  inner sep=0pt,
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={inner sep=0pt},
  column 1/.style=headings,
  column 2/.style={block=block1},
  column 3/.style={block=block2},
  column 4/.style={block=block3},
  column 5/.style={block=block4},
  column 6/.style={block=block5},
  column 7/.style={block=block6},
  column 8/.style={block=block7},
] 
{
Learning unit 1  & & &X&X&X& & \\
Learning unit 2  & & &X&X&X& & \\
Learning unit 3  &X&X&X& &X&X& \\
Learning unit 4  & & &X&X&X&X& \\
Learning unit 5  & & &X&X&X& & \\
Learning unit 6  & & &X&X&X&X&X\\
Learning unit 7  &X&X&X&X&X&X&X\\
Learning unit 8  &X&X& & &X&X& \\
Learning unit 9  &X&X& & &X&X&X\\
Learning unit 10 &X&X& & &X&X& \\
Learning unit 11 &X& & & &X& & \\
Learning unit 12 & & & &X&X&X&X\\
Learning unit 13 & & & &X& &X&X\\
Learning unit 14 &X& & &X&X& & \\
Learning unit 15 &X& & &X&X& & \\
};

\foreach \i in {1,...,14} 
  \draw[gray] (M-\i-1.south west) -- (M-\i-1.south-|M.east);
\draw[thick] (M.south west) rectangle (M.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Instead of drawing a `rectangle` after `matrix`, it's enough to use `draw, thick` inside `matrix` options.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps not as versatile as the answer from JLDiaz, but just as a non-tikz alternative:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}

\newcount\blockcount

\def\blocks#1{\blockcount=0 \doblocks#1@}
\def\doblocks#1{%
 \ifx#1@%
   \hskip.5\extrarowheight{}% 
 \else%
   \advance\blockcount by1 %
   \ifx#1x%
     \doblock{block\the\blockcount}%
   \else%
     \doblock{white}%
   \fi%
   \expandafter\doblocks%
 \fi}

\def\doblock#1{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\raisebox{-.5\extrarowheight}{\vrule width 3ex height3ex depth0.0ex}}%
}
\colorlet{block1}{green!60!yellow!80!black}
\colorlet{block2}{blue!80!red!70!black}
\colorlet{block3}{orange}
\colorlet{block4}{blue!50!cyan}
\colorlet{block5}{orange!50!red}
\colorlet{block6}{yellow}
\colorlet{block7}{black!30}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2in}l@{}|}\hline
Learning unit  1 & \blocks{..xxx..} \\\hline
Learning unit  2 & \blocks{..xxx..} \\\hline
Learning unit  3 & \blocks{xxx.xx.} \\\hline
Learning unit  4 & \blocks{..xxxx.} \\\hline
Learning unit  5 & \blocks{..xxx..} \\\hline
Learning unit  6 & \blocks{..xxxxx} \\\hline
Learning unit  7 & \blocks{xxxxxxx} \\\hline
Learning unit  8 & \blocks{xx..xx.} \\\hline
Learning unit  9 & \blocks{xx..xxx} \\\hline
Learning unit 10 & \blocks{xx..xx.} \\\hline
Learning unit 11 & \blocks{x...x..} \\\hline
Learning unit 12 & \blocks{...xxxx} \\\hline
Learning unit 13 & \blocks{...x.xx} \\\hline
Learning unit 14 & \blocks{x..xx..} \\\hline
Learning unit 15 & \blocks{x..xx..} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

can be done with a simple tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames,X11names]{xcolor}
\def\myBox{\rule[-1.5ex]{5ex}{5ex}}
\def\W{\phantom{\myBox}}
\def\G{\textcolor{green}{\myBox}}
\def\V{\textcolor{blue!100!red!80}{\myBox}}
\def\B{\textcolor{blue}{\myBox}}
\def\O{\textcolor{orange}{\myBox}}
\def\R{\textcolor{red}{\myBox}}
\def\Y{\textcolor{yellow}{\myBox}}
\def\g{\textcolor{gray}{\myBox}}
\begin{document}
{\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=1pt
\fbox{%
\arrayrulecolor{black!20}\arrayrulewidth=0.8pt%
\begin{tabular}{ >{Learning unit }p{0.4\linewidth}l}
1 & \W\W\O\B\R\W\W \\\hline
2 & \W\W\O\B\R\W\W \\\hline
3 & \G\V\O\W\R\Y\W \\\hline
4 & \W\W\O\W\R\Y\W \\\hline
5 & \W\W\O\W\R\W\W \\\hline
6 & \G\V\O\W\R\Y\g \\\hline
7 & ...
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to play with active characters you can simplify the tabluar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames,X11names]{xcolor}
\def\mybox{\rule[-1.5ex]{5ex}{5ex}}
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`\W=\active \catcode`\G=\active 
  \catcode`\V=\active \catcode`\B=\active 
  \catcode`\O=\active \catcode`\R=\active 
  \catcode`\Y=\active \catcode`\K=\active 
  \@firstofone{\endgroup
    \newenvironment{makeActive}{%
      \catcode`\W=\active \catcode`\G=\active 
      \catcode`\V=\active \catcode`\B=\active 
      \catcode`\O=\active \catcode`\R=\active 
      \catcode`\Y=\active \catcode`\K=\active 
      \def W{\phantom{\mybox}}%   white box
      \def G{\textcolor{green}{\mybox}}%
      \def V{\textcolor{blue!100!red!80}{\mybox}}%
      \def B{\textcolor{blue}{\mybox}}%
      \def O{\textcolor{orange}{\mybox}}%
      \def R{\textcolor{red}{\mybox}}%
      \def Y{\textcolor{yellow}{\mybox}}%
      \def K{\textcolor{gray}{\mybox}}%
    }{}%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{makeActive}
\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=1pt
\fbox{\arrayrulecolor{black!20}\arrayrulewidth=0.8pt%
\begin{tabular}{ >{Learning unit }p{0.4\linewidth}l}
1 & WWOBRWW \\\hline
2 & WWOBRWW \\\hline
3 & GVOWRYW \\\hline
4 & WWOWRYW \\\hline
5 & WWOWRWW \\\hline
6 & GVOWRYK 
%7 & ...
\end{tabular}}
\end{makeActive}

\end{document}
```