# Efficiently colouring block of table cells

Tags: tables, color

I made a table with the following code and the `hhline` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l || l l l l l | l}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\\hhline{=#=====|=}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\\hline
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Now, I would like to colour the 5×5 block in a specific colour, and the 1×1 block in another colour. The other cells should remain as they are.

I have seen [Color merged and regular cells in a table individually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8891/23992) which suggests `\cellcolor`, `\rowcolor` and `columncolor` - however, in this case I could only use `\cellcolor`, since there are no full rows or columns. But that would mean I have to type 26 times `\cellcolor`. Is there no efficient way to do this (either algorithmically or by colouring a whole block at once)?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm sorry, I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Manual Solution:** You can apply `\rowcolor` and selectively color in white the cells which should not have color

   [image]
2. **`\ColorBlock{<start row>}{<end row>}{<color>}`**
   Using `collcell` package we can define a macro which specifies which rows of the table to color. This applies only to columns with the `L` alignment defined in the MWE.

   [image]

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand{\RowColor}{\rowcolor{red!50} \cellcolor{white}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l || l l l l l | l}
                  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \cellcolor{yellow}6 \\\hhline{=#=====|=}
\RowColor       1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cellcolor{white}0  \\
\RowColor       2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cellcolor{white}0  \\
\RowColor       3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cellcolor{white}0  \\
\RowColor       4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cellcolor{white}0  \\
\RowColor       5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cellcolor{white}0  \\\hline
\cellcolor{cyan}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{green}1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `\ColorBlock{<start row>}{<end row>}{<color>}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{collcell}

\newcounter{CurrentRow}
\newcommand*{\StartRow}{1}%
\newcommand*{\EndRow}{1}%
\newcommand*{\CellColor}{white}%
\newcommand{\ColorBlock}[3]{%
    \renewcommand*{\StartRow}{#1}%
    \renewcommand*{\EndRow}{#2}%
    \renewcommand*{\CellColor}{#3}%
}

\newcommand*{\ApplyCellColor}[1]{%
    \ifnum\arabic{CurrentRow}>\numexpr\StartRow-1\relax
        \ifnum\arabic{CurrentRow}<\numexpr\EndRow+1\relax
            \cellcolor{\CellColor}#1%
        \else
            #1%
        \fi
    \else
        #1%
    \fi
}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\ApplyCellColor}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}%%  for left alignment
%\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\ApplyCellColor}{c}<{\endcollectcell}}%% if need center alignment
%\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyCellColor}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}%% if need right alignment

\newcommand{\RowColor}{\rowcolor{red!50} \cellcolor{white}}

\newcommand{\EndOfRow}{\stepcounter{CurrentRow}\\}% So that we know when we have ended a row
\newenvironment{MyTabular}[1]{%
    \setcounter{CurrentRow}{1}%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
}{%
    \end{tabular}%
    \gdef\CellColor{white}%
}


\begin{document}
\ColorBlock{2}{6}{red} 
\begin{MyTabular}{l || L L L L L | l}
       & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \EndOfRow\hhline{=#=====|=}
     1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow
     2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow
     3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow
     4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow
     5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow\hline
     6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{MyTabular}\verb|\ColorBlock{2}{6}{red}:|

\medskip
\ColorBlock{3}{5}{cyan} 
\begin{MyTabular}{l || L L L L L | l}
       & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \EndOfRow\hhline{=#=====|=}
     1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow
     2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow
     3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow
     4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow
     5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \EndOfRow\hline
     6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{MyTabular}\verb|\ColorBlock{3}{5}{cyan}:|

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! I was kind of hoping for a solution in the line of `\colorblock{start-col}{end-col}{start-row}{end-row}{color}`, but, I suppose that doesn't exist. This works, thanks!

Comment: @CamilStaps: That could be programmed with the `collcell` package, but if you are only doing a few tables then it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Oh - no, then it's not worth the effort. But I'll bookmark that!

Comment: @CamilStaps: Revised solution which defines a `\ColorBlock` macro similar to what you described.

Comment: Very nice, now I can decide which answer to accept :) even though it's not worth it for just one table

Answer (score 4):

If you color the cells, you need no rule. And you never need vertical rules in tables (nor double rules).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l *{5}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}l} l}
\rowcolor{white}%
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\rowcolor{white}%
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{green!20}1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\rowcolor` takes precedence over `\columncolor` and `\cellcolor` overrides both.

Comment: I just made the double lines here to clearly show the blocks. I know that double lines are evil :) anyway, this works, thanks!

Comment: @CamilStaps Good to know! Go ahead and build the best tables!

Answer (score 1):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have commands in the `\CodeBefore` to color the cells, rectangles, rows or columns you want.

You *won't* have the thin white lines you see in some PDF viewers at some levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lllllll}
\CodeBefore
  \rectanglecolor{blue!20}{2-2}{6-6}
  \cellcolor{green!20}{7-7}
\Body
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]