# tabularray individual cell colouring

Tags: highlighting, cell, tabularray

I am attempting to colour specific cells in a table. I have tried recommendations such as [color only a cell of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50349/color-only-a-cell-of-a-table/50351) and [Efficiently colouring block of table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213301/efficiently-colouring-block-of-table-cells), but when I try the code, only a text appears in my table. My MWE (with help from Zarko and Mico) is shown below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,
    labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth,
         hlines, vlines,
         colspec={*{12}{X[c,m]}},
         colsep=4pt,
         row{1}={ht=7ex},
         row{2}={ht=5ex},
         hspan=minimal
        } 
\SetCell[c=4]{c} I want this to align vertically
&   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c} I want this to align vertically
    &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c} I want this to align vertically
        &   &   &                                                   \\
\SetCell[c=4]{c} Left
&   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c} Center
    &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c} Right
        &   &   &                                                   \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c} {Same\\ here}
&   \SetCell[r=2]{c} {Same\\ here}
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} {Ambient\\ Conditions}
        &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c} {Same\\ here}
                &   \SetCell[r=2]{c} {Same\\ here}
                    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} {Ambient\\ Conditions}
                        &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c} {Same\\ here}
                                &   \SetCell[r=2]{c} {Same\\ here}
                                    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} {Ambient\\ Conditions}
                                        &                           \\
&     & RH  & Temp &   &    & RH  & Temp &  &   & RH  & Temp        \\
A   & 200 & 200 & 200  & A & 200 & 200  & 200 & A   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\ 
B   & 200 & 200 & 200  & B & 200 & 200  & 200 & B   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\
C   & 200 & 200 & 200  & C & 200 & 200  & 200 & C   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\
D   & 200 & 200 & 200  & D & 200 & 200  & 200 & D   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\
E   & 200 & 200 & 200  & E & 200 & 200  & 200 & E   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In this example, I want to colour "Left" in blue, "Center" in green and "Right" in red. Thank you so much.

Comment: Interestingly, you use my answer on your previous question, but you accept other, non-tabularray one :-(. Why you not than stik with it? If meanwhile change the mind, than please accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the desired color through the `\SetCell` command, for example as follows:

```
\SetCell[c=4]{c, blue} Left
&   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c, green} Center
    &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c, red} Right
        &   &   &                                                   \\
```

[image]

Comment: Black text on blue is hard to read. It would be better to use `blue7`, `green7` and `red7` instead.

Comment: @leandriis. Thank you so much.

Comment: @L.J.R. Thank you. I was wondering if there were varying shades of these colours. Much appreciated.

Comment: Note that the SetCell command comes from the tabularray package!

Answer (score 2):

I mainly work with large tables generated by other applications and only imported into latex for publication.

For me, the most important feature of the `tabularray` package is that it can make very clean code by completely separating the styles from the content.

Even if the table changes before the final version, as it usually happens, it is easy to update the content without having to go through the painful review of the cells values, cell by cell, again.

At the same time, different co-workers' inputs on the style can be tested without accidentally changing a cell content.

Coloring the second row is a trivial task.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,
labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth,
                    hlines, vlines,
                    colspec={*{12}{X[c,m]}},
                    colsep=4pt,
                    row{1}={ht=7ex},
                    row{2}={ht=5ex},
                    hspan=minimal,  
                    cell{1}{1}={c=4}{c},
                    cell{1}{5}={c=4}{c},    
                    cell{1}{9}={c=4}{c},
                    cell{2}{1}={c=4}{c,blue!20}, % shaded colors added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    cell{2}{5}={c=4}{c,green!50!black!10},  
                    cell{2}{9}={c=4}{c,red!15},
                    cell{3}{1}={r=2}{c},    
                    cell{3}{2}={r=2}{c},
                    cell{3}{3}={c=2}{c},
                    cell{3}{5}={r=2}{c},    
                    cell{3}{6}={r=2}{c},
                    cell{3}{7}={c=2}{c},
                    cell{3}{9}={r=2}{c},    
                    cell{3}{10}={r=2}{c},
                    cell{3}{11}={c=2}{c},                                   
            } 
             I want this to align vertically&&&
            &I want this to align vertically&&&   
            &I want this to align vertically&&&\\
            Left&&&&Center&&&&Right&&&\\
             {Same\\ here}&{Same\\ here}&{Ambient\\ Conditions}&
            &{Same\\ here}&{Same\\ here}&{Ambient\\ Conditions}&
            &{Same\\ here}&{Same\\ here}&{Ambient\\ Conditions}&\\
                &     & RH  & Temp &   &     & RH  & Temp &     &     & RH  & Temp  \\
            A   & 200 & 200 & 200  & A & 200 & 200  & 200 & A   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\ 
            B   & 200 & 200 & 200  & B & 200 & 200  & 200 & B   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\
            C   & 200 & 200 & 200  & C & 200 & 200  & 200 & C   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\
            D   & 200 & 200 & 200  & D & 200 & 200  & 200 & D   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\
            E   & 200 & 200 & 200  & E & 200 & 200  & 200 & E   & 200 & 200 & 200   \\
        \end{tblr}  
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I always suggest to use colors in `ninecolors` package which is automatically loaded by `tabularray` if you use `xcolor`. It is rather easy to choose matching colors with `ninecolors` package.

Comment: @L.J.R `xcolor` was there. I did not know of `nicecolors` . Perhaps it will be mentioned in the update of the `tabularray` manual?

Comment: In fact, I mentioned it since the first version of `tabularray`. You can just write `blue9`, `green9` and `red9` instead of these complicated mixing colors in the code.