# How to place adjacent Tikz-Nodes with the same (dynamic) height and combined width of the usual text width?

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment, size, height, textwidth

I have a command `\entry` which places two tikz-nodes next to each other. How can I make sure both nodes always have the same height (while also keeping the vertical centering of the text inside)?

Also, how come the right node extends the `\linewidth`, if both nodes together (`0.25\linewidth`+`0.75\linewidth`) should be equal to exactly one `\linewidth`? I would expect the total width of both nodes to be equal to the text width of the bottom text. How would I fix that?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    parskip=half,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    right=20mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=30mm,
    showframe,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Font
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{colour-a}{HTML}{eefaea}
\definecolor{colour-b}{HTML}{e8f4f2}

\newcommand\entry[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(node-a)[fill=colour-a, text width=0.25\linewidth] {
            \textbf{#1}
        };
        \node(node-b)[fill=colour-b, right=0pt of node-a, align=left, text width=0.75\linewidth]{
            #2
        };
        \draw[thick] (node-b.south west)--(node-b.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \par % end of previous paragraph
    %\vspace*{1ex}% optional vertical  space in between
}

\begin{document}
    \entry{%
        test1
    }{
        test1
    }

    \entry{%
        test2 \\
        test2 \\
        test2 \\
    }{
        test2
    }

    \entry{%
        test3
    }{
        test3 \\
        test3 \\
        test3 \\
    }

    \entry{%
        test4
    }{
        \footnotesize \blindtext
    }

    \textbf{Bottom Text}: \\
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: On both sides of `text width` twice the `inner xsep` gets added. Re Same height: Potentially [Q107227](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227). Re Vertical alignment: Potentially [Q139719](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139719) (but I don't think you actually want that?)

Comment: You could also measure both nodes and just fill the background accordingly with [the `background` layer](https://tikz.dev/library-backgrounds).

Comment: There might be a convenient solution with `tcolorbox` or `nicematrix` but I don't use those packages myself. You could also just use a `tabular` with one vertical line and [`\cellcolor`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8891).

Answer (score 2):

Your question was answered by Zarko. It is necessary to add twice the inner spacing to the width of the text to obtain the node whose full width will be, e.g. `0.25\textwidth`.

But it's worth considering that using a tabular(x) with a column `X` will simplify the code as the computation to fit to `\linewidth` will be handled internally.

`nicematrix` (uses `tikz` internally) allows the command `Block` to center vertically and color the cell, and also use `\\` inside.

As a bonus, notice that the vertical lines take on the length of the tallest cell.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
parskip=half,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
a4paper,
left=25mm,
right=20mm,
top=25mm,
bottom=30mm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Font
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif

%**************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{ragged2e} %\justifying
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\definecolor{colour-a}{HTML}{eefaea}
\definecolor{colour-b}{HTML}{e8f4f2}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{m{#1}}

\newcommand\dateentry[2]{% *********  changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{P{0.25\textwidth}| X}                  
    \Block[l, fill= colour-a ]{1-1}{#1}&\Block[fill= colour-a]{1-1}{\justifying#2} \\
\end{NiceTabularX}
\par% end of previous paragraph
}
%*********************************************************


\begin{document}

    \dateentry{test1}{test1}
    \dateentry{test1 \\ test2 \\ test2}{test2}
    \dateentry{test3}{ test3 \\ test3 \\ test3}
    \dateentry{test4}{ \footnotesize \blindtext }   
        
\textbf{Bottom Text}: \newline  
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal with `sidebyside` tcolorboxes instead of `TikZ` nodes. In this case the total width is `\linewidth` by deafult without no worries.

`sidebyside` boxes are unbreakable, but as `TiKZ` nodes are also unbreakable, this shouldn't be a problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    hmargin={25mm,20mm}, vmargin={25mm,30mm},
    showframe,
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% Font
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Only if the base font is sans serif

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mysidebysidebox}[1][]{
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=center seam,
    lefthand width=.25\linewidth,
    sharp corners,
    bicolor,
    overlay={\draw[black, very thick] (segmentation.north)--(segmentation.south);},
    frame hidden,
    colback=colour-a,
    colbacklower=colour-b,
    #1
}

\newcommand{\entry}[3][]{%
    \begin{mysidebysidebox}[#1]
    #2\tcblower #3
    \end{mysidebysidebox}
}

\definecolor{colour-a}{HTML}{eefaea}
\definecolor{colour-b}{HTML}{e8f4f2}

\begin{document}
    \entry{%
        test1
    }{
        test1
    }

    \entry{%
        test2 \\
        test2 \\
        test2 \\
    }{
        test2
    }

    \entry{%
        test3
    }{
        test3 \\
        test3 \\
        test3 \\
    }

    \entry[colbacklower=blue!20]{%
        test4
    }{
        \footnotesize \blindtext
    }

    \textbf{Bottom Text}: \\
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Apparently I read the title of the question too superficially:(.

- Your conclusion wrong. See  @Qrrbrbirlbel comment. Possible solution is to define text width for example as

```
text width=0.25\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}
```

- A (relatively) simple way that both nodes will have the same height, is replacing them with one multi part node

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    hmargin={25mm,20mm}, vmargin={25mm,30mm},
    showframe,
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% Font
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\definecolor{colour-a}{HTML}{eefaea}
\definecolor{colour-b}{HTML}{e8f4f2}

\newcommand\entry[2]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mpnh/.style = {
    rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split part fill={colour-a,colour-b},
               }
                 ]
\node (a) [mpnh] {
    \nodepart[text width=0.25\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}]{one} \textbf{#1}
    \nodepart[text width=0.75\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}]{two} #2
                };
\draw[thick] (a.one split north)--(a.one split south);
\end{tikzpicture}\par
}

\begin{document}
    \entry{test 1}{test 1}
    \entry{test 2a\\
           test 2b\\
           test 2c}{test 2}
    \entry{test 3}{test 3a \\
                   test 3b \\
                   test 3c}
    \entry{test 4}{\blindtext}

\textbf{Bottom Text}: \\
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way is use table instead of draw node. With use of the `tabularray` package code is much simpler and shorter:

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin={25mm,20mm}, vmargin={25mm,30mm},
            showframe,
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% Font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{microtype}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pretocmd{\@declaredcolor}{\my@hack@color{#1}}{}{}
\def\my@hack@color#1{\@ifundefined{\@backslashchar color@#1}{\MyDefineColor{#1}}{\relax}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }

\NewDocumentCommand \MyDefineColor { m } {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpa_seq {|} {#1}
  %\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \exp_args:Nnxx \definecolor{#1} { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1} } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\definecolor{colour-a}{HTML}{eefaea}
\definecolor{colour-b}{HTML}{e8f4f2}
\newcommand\entry[2]%
{
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[1, l,   bg={HTML|eefaea}] | 
                        X[3, j,m, bg={HTML|e8f4f2}]}}
\textbf{#1} &   #2  
\end{tblr}\par
}

\begin{document}
    \entry{test 1}{test 1}
    \entry{test 2a\\
           test 2b\\
           test 2c}{test 2}
    \entry{test 3}{test 3a \\
                   test 3b \\
                   test 3c}
    \entry{test 4}{\small   \blindtext}

\textbf{Bottom Text}: \\
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]