# How to color the text-line-background in a table?

Tags: tables, color

I'd like to color the background of a single line of text in a some cells of a table. I need to obtain a result like this:

[image]

I have tried with `\columncolor` and `\cellcolor` but they don't leave me a white border. Here is my sample code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    ID: \cellcolor{gray}{0.9} & blabla &  blabla \\ \hline
    Title: & blabla & blabla \\ \hline
    State: & blabla & blabla\\ \hline
    Description: & blabla & blabla \\ \hline
    Type: & blabla  & blabla \\ \hline
    Priority: & blabla & blabla \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fill table cells with a background color?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-do-i-fill-table-cells-with-a-background-color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\celltitle[1]{{\fboxrule=0pt\fbox{\colorbox[gray]{0.9}{\makebox[3cm]{#1}}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \celltitle{ID:}  & blabla &  blabla \\ \hline
    \celltitle{Title:} & blabla & blabla \\ \hline
    \celltitle{State:} & blabla & blabla\\ \hline
    \celltitle{Description:} & blabla & blabla \\ \hline
    \celltitle{Type:} & blabla  & blabla \\ \hline
    \celltitle{Priority:} & blabla & blabla \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple adjustment of your code. It requires the packages `color` and `colortbl`. The key point is to define the colour using a `\definecolor` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{color,colortbl} 
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \cellcolor{Gray}ID:  & blabla &  blabla \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{Gray}Title: & blabla & blabla \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{Gray}State: & blabla & blabla\\ \hline
    \cellcolor{Gray}Description: & blabla & blabla \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{Gray}Type: & blabla  & blabla \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{Gray}Priority: & blabla & blabla \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't give me the white border around the coulored text.