# How do I color table columns?

Tags: tables, color

I've found question [How do I fill table cells with a background color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/), but the link to the documentation isn't helping me at all.

I'd like to know how to color a table *column* given my column code, but the documentation only gives the syntax of the command. It doesn't give any code example of where to use it.

```
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}128&64&32&16&8&4&2&1\\\hline
        1&0&1&1&0&1&0&1\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see, I got `\cellcolor` to work, but I don't want to color individual cells. I want to color a whole column of the table. Does anybody know how I can go about to do this?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Here a small example, which might be of help to you.

- Define your own color using `\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}`
- Define your own columns using `\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}`
- You are ready to go.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}

\begin{document} 


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l | a | b | a | b}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
\mc{1}{}  & \mc{1}{x} & \mc{1}{y} & \mc{1}{w} & \mc{1}{z} \\
\hline
variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
variable 2 & a & b & c & d \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: can i make columncolor overwrite rowcolor?

Comment: Note that the column names cannot be more than a single character!

Answer (score 50):

You can use `\columncolor` as

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
```

## code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        128&64&32&16&8&4&2&1\\\hline
        1&0&1&1&0&1&0&1\\\hline
        1&0&1&1&0&1&0&1\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this answer could be much more useful with a bit of explanation about e.g. what 0.8 is and how the syntax can be understood.

Comment: 0.8 is the gray value (1 means white and 0 means black)

Comment: This code doesn't compile to me, I had to change the brackets of the color with {}

Comment: You can also use, in the same way, `>{\columncolor[RGB]{230, 242, 255}}`. Remember, however, to load the package `xcolor` together with `colortbl`.
At this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) you can find a good color picker.

Comment: \begin{tabular}{cc >{\columncolor{magenta}} c} This worked for me, for a table with 3 columns, and last column filled with Magenta color.

Comment: Why do you need a great than symbol `>` for this to actually compile?

Answer (score 8):

It’s easy peasy to color cells/rows/columns with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|},
    row{2} = {purple7},
    column{3} = {teal7},
    cell{2}{3} = {yellow7},
  }
    \hline
      128 & 64 & 32 & 16 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
    \hline
        1 &  0 &  1 &  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
        1 &  0 &  1 &  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can color a column with the same syntax as in `{tabular}` (when `colortbl` is loaded) with the advantage that you will have a perfect PDF output: rules won't seem to vanish and you won't see thin white lines, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|>{\columncolor{blue!15}}c|cc}[colortbl-like]
A & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
B & 4 & 5 & 10 \\
C & 9 & 12 & 15
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of both codes]

It's also possible to specify instructions to color columns (or cells, rows, etc.) in the `\CodeBefore` before the contents of the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|cc}
\CodeBefore
  \columncolor{blue!15}{2}
\Body
  A & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  B & 4 & 5 & 10 \\
  C & 9 & 12 & 15
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

More generally, you can fill an column (or any zone of the tabular) with any pattern of Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|cc}
  A & \Block[tikz={top color=blue!15}]{*-1}{}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
  B & 4 & 5 & 10 \\
  C & 9 & 12 & 15
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]