# Table column not align if give color for Table entries

Tags: tables, color, supertabular

My code follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll>{\color{red}}p{20pc}}
a &1 &Test
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output was:

[image]

Some unnecessary vertical space came before the last column. If I remove the tag `\color{red}` then everything works fine, how can I fix this?

Above said issue was fixed based on the suggestion given by David Carlisle and CarLaTeX, but the same problem was there if I use the `supertabular` environment, I used `supertabular` package for auto breaking table and the code follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color,colortbl,supertabular}
\begin{document}

\begin{supertabular}{ll>{\leavevmode\color{red}}p{4pc}>{\leavevmode\color{black}}l>{\leavevmode\color{black}}l>{\leavevmode\color{red}}p{4pc}}
a &1 &Test &a &1 &Test\\
a &1 &Test &a &1 &Test\\
\end{supertabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The instruction `\usepackage{color,colortbl}` isn't quite correct. You should use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to maximize the interoperability of the `[x]color` and `colortbl` packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `\leavevmode` before `\color{red}`, to ensure that the vertical mode is ended and the horizontal one is entered.

For more info, see: [Function and usage of \leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode) or read the footnote on page 6 of ["Packages in the 'graphics' bundle"](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf). If you have TeX Live, you'll easily find it with `texdoc grfguide` or `texdoc color`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ll>{\leavevmode\color{red}}p{20pc}}
        a &1 & Test \\
    \end{tabular}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = I found the solution in David Carlisles's comment to this question: [How do I color the font in just one row/column without the text jumping a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298199/how-do-i-color-the-font-in-just-one-row-column-without-the-text-jumping-a-line)

Comment: Or of course there is always the documentation: `texdoc grfguide` footnote on page 6:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there some who reads the documentation? :):):) However, in this case, it is a bit difficult to link the problem with that document...

Comment: `texdoc color` also works, of course `texdoc xcolor` probably works as well but the documentation there is longer (and naturally I haven't read that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `xcolor` documentation only cite `\leavevmode` when it talks about `\textcolor`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and CarLaTeX both of your suggestion works fine for normal tabular, if I use supertabular then the same problem happens, please refer the modified question...

Comment: @Balaji Can't you use `longtable` instead of `supertabular`? This works: `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ll>{\color{red}}p{4pc}ll>{\color{red}}p{4pc}}
a &1 &Test &a &1 &Test\\
a &1 &Test &a &1 &Test\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}`

Comment: @CarLaTeX After changing longtable working fine, thanks a lot...

Comment: @Balaji You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 2):

supertablular apparently changes the table preamble not to be colour safe, adding extra groups fixes that (but adds additional vertical space unless you add negative space at the end of p columns)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color,colortbl,supertabular}
\begin{document}

\begin{supertabular}{
l
l
>{\bgroup\leavevmode\color{red}}p{4pc}<{\endgraf\egroup}
>{\bgroup\leavevmode\color{black}}l<{\egroup}
>{\bgroup\leavevmode\color{black}}l<{\egroup}
>{\bgroup\leavevmode\color{red}}p{4pc}<{\endgraf\egroup}
}
a &1 &Test &a &1 &Test\\
a &1 &Test &a &1 &Test\\
\end{supertabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it documented? LOL (btw, +1, of course)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I doubt it (but didn't look:-)

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea why it happened! but using the `m` option as defined in `array` package will solve the issue.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll>{\color{red}}m{20pc}}
a &1 &Test\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no this does not solve the issue, and causes another issue that the baseline of Test is no longer the same as that of a 1.  The issue is documented in the main graphics package documentaion `texdoc grfguide` footnote page 6.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
Thanks for the explanation, but why does `m` work?!

Comment: m does not work, as I said in the initial comment, it vertically centres `Test` so it is no longer baseline aligned with "a" and "1" (`b` would be better than `m`) The alignment changes for `p` as the first item in the cell is a colour node not the first line of text.