# How to format table background colour, horizontal lines and captions?

Tags: tables

I need to create an array  like this with latex:
[image]

I try by using this code by I failed:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
  \hline
  Security mode & Security provided \\
  \hline
  \hline
  No Security & Data is not encrypted \\
  \hline
  AES-CBC-MAC-32 & Data is not encrypted\\
  \hline  
  AES-CBC-MAC-64 & Data is not encrypted\\
  \hline  
  AES-CBC-MAC-128 & Data is not encrypted\\
  \hline  
  AES-CTR & Data is encrypted\\
  \hline  
  AES-CCM-32 & Data is encrypted\\
  \hline  
  AES-CCM-64 & Data is encrypted\\
  \hline  
  AES-CCM-128 & Data is encrypted\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{\label{tab:tab1}Security modes in the IEEE802.15.4e Standard.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The code works for me, it produces a table. What do you mean by "failed"? Do you get an error? What does the output look like?

Comment: @FLonLon It works for me too, but i need to have the table in the figure.

Comment: @FLonLon  I failed to have the same.

Comment: you mean the grey colour at the top? or the caption on the top instead of bottom?

Comment: yes  exactly, I want the same format

Comment: Ah, I see. You can find a solution to colour the cells here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94799/how-do-i-color-table-columns/ and you can move the caption to the top by literally just moving the `\caption` command before the `\begin{tabular}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve a table such as this, you need to adjust the following:

1. Background colour of the top row. Packages: `xcolor` + `colortbl`
2. The double horizontal line at the top. Package: `hhline`
3. The format of the caption. Package: `caption`

You define a light grey colour with `\definecolor{mygrey}{rgb}{211,211,211}` and in the table you then use `\rowcolor{mygrey}`. The double horizontal lines are achieved by using `\hhline{==}`. The caption is formatted through two commands:

1. `\captionsetup{justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=sc,labelsep = newline}` It centers the caption, turns font into small-caps, and provides a new line after the name
2. `\renewcommand*\thetable{\Roman{table}}` This changes the table numbering to Roman numerals.

This code will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,hhline,caption}
\definecolor{mg}{RGB}{211,211,211}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=sc,labelsep = newline}
    \renewcommand*\thetable{\Roman{table}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
    \caption{\label{tab:tab1}
    \scshape{{Security modes in the IEEE802.15.4e Standard.}}}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c}
            \hhline{==}
            \rowcolor{mg}
            Security mode & Security provided \\\hline
            \hhline{==}
            No Security & Data is not encrypted \\\hline
            AES-CBC-MAC-32 & Data is not encrypted\\\hline  
            AES-CBC-MAC-64 & Data is not encrypted\\\hline  
            AES-CBC-MAC-128 & Data is not encrypted\\\hline  
            AES-CTR & Data is encrypted\\\hline  
            AES-CCM-32 & Data is encrypted\\\hline  
            AES-CCM-64 & Data is encrypted\\\hline  
            AES-CCM-128 & Data is encrypted\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: table formatted in the way the OP wants]

Comment: You can just load `xcolor` with option `table`: it will automatically load `colortbl`.