# How to highlight the first column of Table?

Tags: tables

I have enclosed the sample code of a Routh Array Table. I wish to highlight the first column of the Table.

One way to do is to run the LaTeX, get a PDF output, save as image, highlight the first column using Paint or such software, and call the image using the Figure environment in LaTeX. This seems to be quite a long route!

I'd like to know if there is a direct way to mark the first column of the Routh Array in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}
The Routh array is:

 
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
$s^3$ & $1$ & $2$ \\[2mm]
$s^2$ & $1$ & $24$ \\[2mm]
$s^1$ & $-22$ & $0$ \\[2mm]
$s^0$ & $24$ & $0$ \\[2mm]
\end{tabular}
 

\end{document}
```

[image: Desired Output of Routh Array Table]

Comment: See this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94799/how-do-i-color-table-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the packages `xcolor` and `colortbl` to define a color `Higlight` and a new column type `h`. This produces:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{Highlight}{HTML}{FFF59C}
\newcolumntype{h}{>{\columncolor{Highlight}}c}

\begin{document}
The Routh array is:
 
\begin{tabular}{c|hc}
$s^3$ & $1$ & $2$ \\[2mm]
$s^2$ & $1$ & $24$ \\[2mm]
$s^1$ & $-22$ & $0$ \\[2mm]
$s^0$ & $24$ & $0$ \\[2mm]
\end{tabular}
 

\end{document}
```

---

You can change the color by defining your own color with `\definecolor{name}{type}{value}` where type can be `RGB`, `rgb`, `cmyk` or `HTML` (hex). Here is how to provide values for them:

- `RGB`: 3 numbers between 0 and 255: {1,18,240}
- `rgb` 3 numbers between 0 and 1: {0.5,0.1,0}
- `cmyk` 3 numbers between 0 and 1: {0.5,0.1,0}
- `HTML` same as Hex code (1 value, 6 digits): {006600}